# How to fix on Mac OSX EACCES: permission denied...You don't have access to this file

Tags: macos, npm, permissions, sudo

I'm trying to make a new project with gatsby template running the command `gatsby new website-public https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default` in Terminal window, but I constantly getting this error:

```
 gatsby new website-public https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/delilah/.config/gatsby/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
    at Ti._i.globalConfigPath.get all [as all] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:155965)
    at new Ti._i.globalConfigPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:155924)
    at Ti (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:155721)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/node_modules/create-gatsby/lib/index.js:1:486075)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

I have tried with following:

1. sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
2. sudo chown -R `whoami`
   /usr/local/lib/node_modules

But nothing helps, I'm using Mac OSX.

If anyone has some idea, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that `/Users/delilah/.config/gatsby/config.json` is the file you don't have access to, so that's the file you have to `chown` and/or `chmod` to fix, not paths you list as having tried.

Comment: so anything to do to fix this? Thanks

Comment: "so anything to do to fix this?" Yes, it's right there in the answer. You have to chown and/or chmod the file so you have access to it. In your question, you mention chown and chmod, but you are running it on the wrong paths.